# Magic Suggest focus always on first input

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I am about to develop a dynamic inputs inside a panel with magicsuggest function. So i tried to hardcode the elements first in jquery and attached magicsuggest function each. But i am getting issue. As you can see below,

[image]

I have "Request", and "Publishers" to magic suggests inputs. The first ("Request") is okay, i can click on the "trigger" and populate data down. But when i click on the "trigger" of the second input ("Publishers") it only focuses on the "Request". As image below:

[image]

Both 2 inputs have diff id's. Why is that so?
This is the code i used:

```
 var maa = $('#ms-aut').magicSuggest({
    noSuggestionText: 'No matches',
    useCommaKey: true,
    useZebraStyle: true,
    // hideTrigger: true,
    data: ['ONO Natsume', 'YOSHINAGA Fumi', 'YAMAMOTO Kotetsuko', 'ASADA Nemui'],
    });                 

    var baa = $('#ms-art').magicSuggest({
        noSuggestionText: 'No matches',
        useCommaKey: true,
        useZebraStyle: true,
        //  hideTrigger: true,
        data: ['HAYAKAWA Nojiko', 'ymz', 'YAMAMOTO Kotetsuko', 'ASADA Nemui'],
    });
```

Comment: This works without problem https://jsfiddle.net/59r80L6m/. Problem is probably in rest of your code. Can you create jsfiddle with complete code?

Comment: yes its working if the element is loaded in the html form. but if dynamically loaded via jquery it wont

Comment: can you set full code in jsfiddle?

Comment: can we chat? i can give you the codes